# Google Places API call returns results when called with server-side code but not with app script code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-places-api

I have some code that makes a call to the google places API, for certain locations/names however when executing this, it only seems to give a call with results when called server side and not when I called it using the app script method UrlFetch.fetch()

Example being:

```
  var api_key = my_secret_api_key
  var nameOfPlace = "Sketch"
  var location = "London,uk"

var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=" + nameOfPlace + "&key=" + api_key + "&location=" + location

var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)

var response = JSON.parse(request)
```

Results:

```
{"html_attributions" : [], "results" : [], "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"}
```

However if I write the same code using node-fetch or axios or even using Postman client for testing, I get a successful set of results

```
  {"html_attributions" : [],"results" : [{},{},{}],"status" : "OK"}
```

where the results array contains the list of relevant data

I've checked the url and they are identical.

Now the weird thing is, I do get results from some calls when using the app script method, but for some locations, I simply don't even though I have no problems when I call it using server side methods.

Has anyone had this issue before? 
Would you be able to help me diagnose the issue?

Here's a real query that you could try from which I get results "server-code-side" but no results via app script

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json? 
query=Sketch&key={{api_key}}&location=London,uk
```

Comment: I see you've tagged [tag:appscript] - can you be a bit more clear on how this tag is relevant?

Comment: Can you please provide a valid JavaScrpit snippet? The one you've provided as your example will throw syntax errors due to your unbound string. See also: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hey @esqew, thanks for answering and sending that through, I've updated my snippet

Comment: and @esqew the tag is relevant because I'm using google app script, I've edited to describe google app script

Comment: All variables should be urlencoded `encodeURIComponent(location)`

Comment: dvg1`q2w36745//**-/*-+

Comment: @Adrian Samuel - I'm encountering the same issue. Were you able to resolve it?